# How to Securely Store Database Password in Java .properties File

Tags: password-management, databases, java

I would like to store my DB password in Java `.property` file and [encrypt it using `Jasypt`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306673/securing-a-password-in-a-properties-file). But from what I see, it just moves the problem from hiding the DB Password to hiding the encryption password.

I thought of using environment variable to store the encryption password, but it requires effort by the dev to change/set whenever there is a leak, also it will be visible in plaintext somewhere. Besides that, I also thought of using Vault, but the dev team does not seem like they want to implement a dedicated Vault server. I have also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191317/best-practice-for-storing-database-password), and they said that there is no solution 9 years ago..

Is there a (preferably simple) solution to this now?

Comment: Seriously, how can Java be so bad?